# Backbone.js basic connection not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've just started out learning JS, and I have a syntax problem which I'm unable to solve. The error message looks like this:

```
/Users/joseph/bbapp/server.js:5
  connect.static(__dirname)
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joseph/bbapp/server.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

and my server.js file looks like this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var port = 3000;

connect.createServer(
  connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(port);

console.log('you are now connected')
```

Probably a rookie-mistake, but I can't solve it.

Comment: It looks like you are probably using an old tutorial. If you install an older version of connect (2.29.1) rather than the latest version (3.3.5) then your code will run.

Comment: @TylerMarien Okay, I see. Do you know what needs to be done to make this code work?

Comment: See me answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serve-static is no longer included in connect so you will have to install it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static

Then you can use the following code to do the same thing:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));

app.listen(3000);
```